# Safe way of creating unique IDs

Tags: javascript, react.js

Is the code below safe to create unique ids for objects?

I will create new yoga classes and need to have a unique id for each class. I made this small piece of code to generate the id numbers.

Regarding specifically the `uniqueIdCreatorHandler` `method`, would this solution incur in bad performance, or is it just far from elegant?

what would you say?

CodeSandBox [here](https://codesandbox.io/embed/boring-cori-xeq2m?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark)

The code is also presented as per below:

```
import React from "react";

export default class App extends React.Component {
  state = {
    id: "",
    ids: [{ id: 7 }, { id: 14 }]
  };

  uniqueIdCreatorHandler = () => {
    let ids = [...this.state.ids];
    let highestId = 0;
    if (ids.length > 0) {
      highestId = ids
        .map(value => {
          return value.id;
        })
        .reduce((a, b) => {
          return Math.max(a, b);
        });
    }
    let newId = highestId + 1;
    ids.push({ id: newId });
    this.setState({ ids: ids });
  };

  idDeleterHanlder = currIndex => {
    let ids = this.state.ids;
    ids.splice(currIndex, 1);
    this.setState({ ids: ids });
  };

  render() {
    let ids = this.state.ids.map((id, index) => {
      return (
        <p onClick={() => this.idDeleterHanlder(index)} key={id.id}>
          id:{id.id}
        </p>
      );
    });

    return (
      <div className="App">
        <button onClick={this.uniqueIdCreatorHandler}>Push new id</button>
        <p>all ids below:</p>
        {ids}
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: If you delete the last index, and push a new one, it will re-use the same index. I would just keep the last created index as part of the state. The code will be much more elegant.

Answer (score 2):

I've noticed you have a common bug that often occurs in Javascript code called a **race condition**.

If `uniqueIdCreatorHandler` is called again before a previous call finishes there is a race condition created because `state.ids` is replaced at the end of the call.

If both calls happen at the same time they each generate a unique copy of the original `state.ids` then overwrite state `this.setState({ ids: ids });`. This causes the first change to `state.ids` to be forgotten.

**This is a direct result caused by replacing state. `this.setState({ ids: ids });`**

As others have recommend I would simply keep a increment in state for new ids.

*Note: you can easily demonstrate this in your code by adding and calling this method*

```
double = () => {
  this.uniqueIdCreatorHandler()
  this.uniqueIdCreatorHandler()
}
```

*Other comments*
There are small improvements you could make to your code like spreading the mapped ids into Math.max.

I wouldn't worry too much about Javascript performance, focus on readability. Make variable names more verbose and add doc blocks to methods.

One thing I like to see (which you have done) is the embrace of array methods. Although they may not be necessary here they are a strong indicator of comprehension.

Keep it up!

Comment: Thanks so much for shedding some light into this humble piece of code. Regarding the asynchronous nature of ```Js``` I guess that I should somehow implement ```prevState``` ```arg``` once I set my state, correct? like: ```this.setState(prevState => ({id: prevState...do something})```

Comment: For your use case you "shouldn't" run into any situations where pushing to the ids doesn't work. I would say it's something you should be aware of as a potential problem. From what I understand this is because React batches updates. So you would want to merge all of the changes into a single `setState()` or use Promises. *but that is probably over engineering at this point*